Combine two rows in a CSV and preserve the number of columns
I have a CSV file with some values represented thusly:
Superman/, 250lbs, Batman/, 180lbs
Clark Kent, , Bruce Wayne, 

I need to combine the rows such that it looks like:
Superman/Clark Kent, 250lbs, Batman/Bruce Wayne, 180lbs

Obviously I need to delete that second row once merged. Can the CSV library do this? I know there's the extend(...) function, but I need to keep the column number the same.

What are you doing with the data after this modification? Do you just want to read the file in and write out a new one, or are you doing some other processing with the data?

The desired arrangement looks weird, too. A proper normalization would use one record per row, one pair of data items per record. So first row Superman/Clark Kent,250lbs, second row Batman/Bruce Wayne,180lbs. A better normalization still would put the alias in a separate column and leave it empty for someone who does not have an alias (and probably use kilograms instead of Mickey Mouse units).

You can use the csv module's reader to iterate the file row-by-row like normal,
then when you encounter a special row, like "Superman/", read ahead one row and
combine the two.
I also added the skipinitialspace=True keyword to trim leading spaces of each field during the read:
import csv

data: list[list[str]] = []

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "Superman/":
            next_row = next(reader)  # manually iterate reader
            row[0] += next_row[0]
            row[2] += next_row[2]
        data.append(row)

print(data)

With your simple two-row input, data looks like:
[
    ['Superman/Clark Kent', '250lbs', 'Batman/Bruce Wayne', '180lbs']
]

To save the modified data to a new CSV (and I recommend creating a new CSV, verifying the results, and only then replacing the original):
with open("output.csv",'w',newline='')as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)

The output CSV looks like:
Superman/Clark Kent,250lbs,Batman/Bruce Wayne,180lbs

If you don't want or need to mess with the intermediate data list, you can read and write rows in the same pass:
with (
    open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in,
    open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out,
):
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "Superman/":
            next_row = next(reader)  # manually iterate reader
            row[0] += next_row[0]
            row[2] += next_row[2]
        writer.writerow(row)

Note that calling next(reader) moves the reader forward one row. From the start of your sample, reading row 1 then manually reading row 2, when the loop "comes around again" it would be on the 3rd row (if your sample had 3 rows).

Thanks, is there a way to merge with the previous row? If it's in the CSV object anyway, it shouldn't be that hard to grab, right?

This effectively does. You seem to be thinking along the lines of "editing the CSV in place", is that correct? The csv module doesn't provide any functionality for that: you read from one file and write to another (with a csv.writer). If you want to overwrite the original file with the modified contents of the original, then you've effectively edited the original.

The way you use "CSV object" makes me think you're thinking of how an Excel file might be represented in Python. The csv.reader is just an iterator over lists of strings... the only object-oriented aspects of the reader are setting some initial parameters and providing the "dunder" method(s) that enable Pythonic iteration.
